# Extracting rows around patterns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, pattern-matching

I have a data.frame `test` where I would like to identify what comes before and after a `bar` - `foo` pattern for each `id`.  The pattern must be consecutive by `timestamp`

For example, in the following sample there are **three** patterns of `bar` - `foo` that occur.

```
> test
             timestamp id message   result
1  2019-01-01 00:00:21  1     bar negative
2  2019-01-01 00:00:58  1     bar positive
3  2019-01-01 00:01:35  1     foo positive
4  2019-01-01 00:03:02  1     bar negative
5  2019-01-01 00:06:42  1     baz positive
6  2019-01-01 00:07:16  1     baz positive
7  2019-01-01 00:07:39  1     bar positive
8  2019-01-01 00:09:14  2     bar negative
9  2019-01-01 00:09:56  2     foo negative
10 2019-01-01 00:10:56  2     foo positive
11 2019-01-01 00:11:13  2     foo negative
12 2019-01-01 00:11:32  2     foo positive
13 2019-01-01 00:11:49  2     bar negative
14 2019-01-01 00:12:18  2     foo positive
15 2019-01-01 00:15:28  2     bar positive
```

As a result, the ideal output would look like this:

```
> output
    before    after id
1 negative negative  1
2     <NA> positive  2
3 positive positive  2
```

The code I've applied below *works* but seems convoluted and inefficient

```
test %>%
            group_by(id) %>%
            mutate(next.message = lead(message, order_by=timestamp),
                   previous.result = lag(result, order_by=timestamp),
                   next.result = lead(result, n = 2, order_by=timestamp)) %>%
            filter(message == 'bar', next.message == 'foo')  %>%
            filter_all(any_vars(!is.na(.))) %>% 
            select (-c(timestamp, message, result, next.message)) %>%
            rename(before = previous.result , after = next.result)
```

What would be a better way to approach this problem using either `dplyr` or `data.table` functions?

sample data:

```
dput(test)
structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1546318821, 1546318858, 
1546318895, 1546318982, 1546319202, 1546319236, 1546319259, 1546319354, 
1546319396, 1546319456, 1546319473, 1546319492, 1546319509, 1546319538, 
1546319728), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), id = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), message = c("bar", "bar", 
"foo", "bar", "baz", "baz", "bar", "bar", "foo", "foo", "foo", 
"foo", "bar", "foo", "bar"), result = c("negative", "positive", 
"positive", "negative", "positive", "positive", "positive", "negative", 
"negative", "positive", "negative", "positive", "negative", "positive", 
"positive")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)
test[, 
    {
        #find the rows where message is bar and next message is foo
        v <- .I[message=="bar" & shift(message, -1L, fill="")=="foo"]

          #extract the previous result and use NA if its beyond the starting row index of current id
        .(before=test[replace(v - 1L, v - 1L < min(.I), NA_integer_), result],

            #extract the next result and use NA if its beyond the ending row index of current id
            after=test[replace(v + 2L, v + 2L > max(.I), NA_integer_), result])
    },
    by=.(id)]
```

output:

```
   id   before    after
1:  1 negative negative
2:  2     <NA> positive
3:  2 positive positive
```

Comment: I receive the following error: `Error in shift(message, -1L, fill = "") : 
  n must be non-negative integer values (>= 0)`

Comment: `Should one use `type = "lag"` or something instead of negative integer values? `

Comment: you will need to install data.table version >= 1.12.0 or use `shift(message, 1L, type="lag")`

Answer (score 1):

here's my way with `data.table`

```
test_dt <- setDT(test)
# add the before and after to all rows
test_dt[order(timestamp),
        c("before", "after") := list(shift(result, 1, type = 'lag'), 
                                     shift(result, 2, type = 'lead')), 
        by=id]

# filter the rows and select the columns you need
test_dt[message == 'bar' & shift(message, 1, type = 'lead') == 'foo', 
        list(before, after), by = id]
```